# docker container can't find frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I created a visual studio 2022 application which has a few APIs.
I publish to a folder then from there build a docker image, which seems fine.
If i run the solution from Visual Studio it works fine. However trying to turn the docker image to a container i am unable to run the container and get following message.

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: C:\app\SyntaxBuilder.dll

Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\
No frameworks were found.
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet

COPY ["./SyntaxBuilder/bin/Release/net7-windows/publish/","/app"]

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SyntaxBuilder.dll"]
```

Comment: What application are you trying to build? What do you me3an by `a few APIs`? `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` is *definitely* not used in Linux web apps. `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet` is a Linux image used for ASP.NET Core web apps

Comment: this is being built on windows - not linux if that makes any odds? the projects target framework is net7-windows

Comment: You used a Linux web app runtime image. The error says you have a desktop application. Why use containers at all? What are you trying to do?

Comment: how are you able to identify that as linux?

Comment: That image is used in all ASP.NET Core tutorials and doc articles. If you actually look at the [image's page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet?tab=description) you'll see it targets Linux. `latest` is a synonym for `7.0.5-bullseye-slim-amd64`. Bullseye is a Debian version. Like all web servers, all `aspnetcore` images have no desktop components or libraries. You tried to use an image that clearly says `aspnetcore` to run a Window desktop application. Even if you used a Windows version it would probably fail again

Comment: Once again, what are you trying to do? Why are you trying to run a desktop app inside a container at all?

Comment: so you would recommend moving targetframework from net7-windows to just net7.0?

Comment: so i am trying to take my solution, which i am building with .net7, i temporarily had the framework set to net7windows as some packages were of that type (they can be adjusted to net7). then build it into a docker image and deploy it to docker container